Next.js Images not showing
I am unable to display images in my application.
I tried it both with Next.js Image component and with the Image component from @nextui-org/image.
My images are in the public folder and I am referencing it correctly as far as I can judge.
Not sure why I cant display them.
This is the error I get in my shell:
⨯ The requested resource isn't a valid image for /images/whatsapp-white.png received text/html; charset=utf-8
This is the file I am trying to add images to:
import { Navbar, NavbarBrand, NavbarContent, NavbarItem, Link, Button } from "@nextui-org/react";
import Image from "next/image";
import LangNav from "./LangNav";

export default function NavBar({ dict, lang }: { dict: any; lang: string }) {
  return (
    <Navbar className="bg-achi-blue text-primary font-saira">
      <NavbarBrand>
        {/* <p className="font-bold text-inherit">ACHI</p> */}
        {/* <Image alt="whatsapp" width={50} height={50} src="/images/whatsapp-white.png" /> */}
      </NavbarBrand>
      <NavbarContent className="hidden sm:flex gap-[4em]" justify="center">
        <NavbarItem className="flex items-center gap-2">
          <span className="material-symbols-outlined">location_on</span>
          <span className="text-sm">{dict.header.Lebanon}</span>
        </NavbarItem>
        <NavbarItem className="flex items-center gap-2">
          <Link href="#" aria-current="page" className="flex items-center gap-2">
            <span className="material-symbols-outlined">mail</span>
            <span className="text-sm">prego@achiponteggi.it</span>
          </Link>
        </NavbarItem>
        <NavbarItem className="flex items-center gap-2">
          <Link href="#" className="flex items-center gap-2">
            <Image width={50} height={50} src="/images/whatsapp-white.png" alt="whatsapp" />
            <span className="text-sm">+393318007652</span>
          </Link>
        </NavbarItem>
      </NavbarContent>
      <NavbarContent justify="end">
        <NavbarItem className="flex items-center ">
          <LangNav dict={dict} lang={lang} />
        </NavbarItem>
      </NavbarContent>
    </Navbar>
  );
}

The image itself is showing. It's a .png image. I tried it with other images they don't work either.
I added images to the public/images folder and specified the path in my component, sadly with no success.

You seem to be doing it right, can you share a codesandbox, I can help take a look
